# Failed to disable UserInteraction on UIView added on UIWindow

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiwindow, isuserinteractionenabled

So here is the problem. I have created a custom loader which shows a basic "loading" text in the middle with dimmed background. The HUD shows just fine but despite of setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` I still can click on the UI where I have added the HUD. Here is the code:

```
public class Loader {
    public static let shared = Loader()
    
    private(set) var containerView = UIView()
    private(set) var lblText = UILabel()
    
    private init() {
        self.containerView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        self.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.5)
        self.containerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        lblText.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
        lblText.textAlignment = .center
        lblText.textColor = .white
        lblText.text = "Loading..."
        containerView.addSubview(lblText)
        
        lblText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: lblText, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: lblText, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: lblText, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 275).isActive = true
        lblText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblText.widthAnchor, multiplier: 181/375).isActive = true
    }
    
   
    public func show() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
            if let found = UIApplication.key?.subviews.contains(where: {$0 == self.containerView}), found {
                self.containerView.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self.containerView)
            }
            else {
                UIApplication.key?.addSubview(self.containerView)
            }
        })
    }
    
    @objc public func hide() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
            self.containerView.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    static var key: UIWindow? {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
                .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
                .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
                .compactMap({$0})
                .first?.windows
                .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
        } else {
            // do lower version specific window setup
            return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: `Loader.shared.show()` and `Loader.shared.hide()`

Whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
   Maybe when you show the loader you can change the main view isUserInteractionEnabled to false and after you will finish the loading process change it again to true?
    
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
               Loader.shared.show()
               self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            }
```